# Get values from two text-box and display sum of that on template in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to display sum value in template page using meteor.js.

Here is my html code:

```
<head>
    <title>Sum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sum of two values</h1>

    {{> sumForm}}   
</body>

<template name="sumForm">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="value1"> + <input type="text" name="value2"><p>Total: {{totalSum}}</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sum">
    </form>
</template>
```

and my js code:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

    Template.sumForm.events({

        'submit form': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            value1Var = parseInt(event.target.value1.value);
            value2Var = parseInt(event.target.value2.value);

            Template.sumForm.totalSum = value1Var + value2Var;

            return Template.sumForm.totalSum;           
        }
    });
}
```

But this does not work.

Can any one help?

Comment: Is the submit event not getting run?  What doesn't work about it?

Comment: submit event works. but the issue is i m not able to print result in template here ->Total: {{totalSum}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user reactive-var to achive what you want

First you have to add the lightweight reactive-var package

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Then at your Template file add:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.sumForm.created = function () {
    //We set default value
    this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
  }
  Template.sumForm.helpers({
    totalSum: function () {
     return Template.instance().counter.get();
    }
 });
 Template.sumForm.events({
   'submit form': function(event, template){
   event.preventDefault();

   value1Var = parseInt(event.target.value1.value);
   value2Var = parseInt(event.target.value2.value);

   var sum = value1Var + value2Var;
   return template.counter.set(sum);;
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.sumForm.helpers({
  totalSum: function(){
    return Session.get("sum");
  }    
});
```

And at the end of your submit event

```
Session.set("sum", value1Var + value2Var);
```

For a cleaner solution also consider using reactive-var instead of session variables.

Comment: that's fine. but i need to display totalSum value on my button submit or click. is it possible how?

Comment: totalSum will reactively change if you use the session variable's.

Comment: without session does it possible ?

Comment: You can use the reactive-var package.  It's the same concept, without polluting the global space.